# How to validate a date string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

OK, so there's a bunch of answers on related topics, but for some reason it seems that no one is interested in the following very-real problem:

I have a `Timecard` model, with `to_date` and `from_date` fields. I'm using `jquery.ui.datepicker` and generally speaking - all is well. I'm also using the 'validates_timeliness' gem:

```
class Timecard < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_date :to_date
  validates_date :from_date
  ...
end
```

However, if the user decides to manually edit the text field, entering something like '29-Feb-2013' (which is an invalid date), this date will be converted to '01-Mar-2013'. The following spec will fail:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  ...
  context "with invalid attributes (invalid date)" do
    it "re-renders the :new template" do
      timecard = fix_date_attribs_for(:timecard_feb)
       # Manually create an invalid date in the params hash - Feb only has 28 days
      timecard['to_date(3i)'] = 29
      post :create, timecard: timecard
      response.should render_template :new
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The following `puts` in **timecards_controller.rb**:

```
def create
  @timecard = Timecard.new(timecard_params)
  puts ">>>> #{@timecard.valid?} - #{@timecard.to_yaml}"
  ...
end
```

yields the following output when running the above spec:

```
.>>>> true - --- !ruby/object:Timecard
attributes:
  id: 
  name: February 2013
  from_date: 2013-02-01
  to_date: 2013-03-01
  created_at: 
  updated_at: 
F

Failures:

  1) TimecardsController POST #create with invalid attributes (invalid date) re-renders the :new template
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template :new
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/timecards_controller_spec.rb:65:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28495 seconds
17 examples, 1 failure
```

How do I do input validation here? Using callbacks in the model seem too far off (since the problem occurs before - when the controller does `@timecard = Timecard.new(timecard_params)`). I could try to catch a `Date.new(relevant_timecard_params)` exception in the controller, but it doesn't have access to the `errors` hash so I wouldn't be able to tell the user it's an invalid date, not to mention that the controller doesn't sound like the right place to do input validation... Please help...

## Update 1

With 'validate_timeliness' as @Grantovich suggested below (with the plugin enabled) and `save` and `update` fail with invalid dates such as '29-Feb-2013' even without writing `validates_date :to_date` in the model. When adding `validates_date`, `save` and `update` fail and the validated fields are set to `nil` even on perfectly valid input (by the validation logic, I suspect).

Also tried specifying the format: `validates_date :to_date, format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy'` but got the same results.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention it, but currently the form would not save the bad '29-Feb-2013' date. It's just that it doesn't display any message to the user, nor is it testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing comes from the standard Ruby time parser, which validates_timeliness uses by default. You can see this by manually running your example through `Time.parse`:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.parse('29-Feb-2013')
=> 2013-03-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

[This section of the validates_timeliness README](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness#plugin-parser) says the optional `timeliness` parser is "more strict than the Ruby parser, which means it won’t accept day of the month if it’s not a valid number for the month". This seems like exactly the behavior you want, so I'd try putting the following in a `validates_timeliness.rb` initializer (or adding the config line if you already have one):

```
ValidatesTimeliness.setup do |config|
  config.use_plugin_parser = true
end
```

Comment: I suggest to apply rescue after Date/Time parsers to avoid exceptions `Time.parse('35-Feb-2013') rescue nil`

Comment: I've removed the 'validates_timeliness' gem and changed my form to localise the date if it exists:

      <%= f.text_field :from_date, :class => 'datepicker',
    :value => @timecard.from_date.nil? ? nil : l(@timecard.from_date) %>

Wrong dates are nullified now (and the validate :presence validation says they "can't be blank).

Comment: OK, back with 'validates_timeliness' (removing it left things in a very partial state). Now the issue is that the rspec example fails.

Comment: Your spec sets the param `to_date(3i)` as though emulating a multi-dropdown date selector. [As explained here in the README](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness#strict-parsing-for-select-helpers), by default validates_timeliness is not invoked when parsing multi-parameter date values. Since you're using a standard text field for the date input, you should update your spec to reflect how the data would actually come in (i.e. a single `to_date` param containing a string like `"29-Feb-2013"`).

Comment: Thanks! Silly me. I removed the leftover helper methods and manipulated the text field directly as you suggested and now the test works :)